# Making ASCII with C#?

Tags: c#, loops, oop, ascii

I need to do some kind of an artwork for my homework. Given is an byte array, which I need to be displayed as 7 lines with 11 characters each line but I really can't find out how to structure it, also, I'm recieving a System.IO.EndOfStreamExeption (which connects to the while part). In the end, I'm pretty sure it's supposed to display "C#" on the console.

```
internal class Program
{
    public void ESAIn(string Path)
    {
        byte[] array = { 32, 32, 67, 67, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                        32, 67, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                        67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
                        67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                        67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
                        32, 67, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                        32, 32, 67, 67, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32 };

        FileStream stream = File.Open(Path, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        stream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public void ESAOut(string Path)
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(Path, FileMode.Open));
        var count = 0;
        int b;

        while ((b = reader.ReadByte()) > -1)
        {
            Console.Write((char)b);
            if (count > 0 && (++count % 11) == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes("myFile.dat", array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to save the `byte[]` into a file, call `File.WriteAllBytes`

```
 byte[] array = ...

 File.WriteAllBytes("myFile.dat", array);
```

But you seem to want to convert every `11` bytes into a `string` and only then save these strings into a file. We can do it by querying `array` with a help of *Linq*:

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 byte[] array = ...

 var lines = array
   .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
   .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / 11, pair => pair.value)
   .Select(group => string.Concat(group.Select(b => (char)b)));

 File.WriteAllLines("myFile.txt", lines);
```

Now `myFile.txt` contains

```
  CC   # # 
 C  C  # # 
C     #####
C      # # 
C     #####
 C  C  # # 
  CC   # #
```

**Edit:** If you want store `array` as it is:

```
 File.WriteAllBytes("myFile.dat", array);
```

To load the file and display the art you can use `File.ReadAllBytes` to get `byte[]` and then *Linq* to have a text representation:

```
 string art = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File
   .ReadAllBytes("myFile.dat")
   .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
   .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / 11, pair => pair.value)
   .Select(group => string.Concat(group.Select(b => (char)b)))
 );

 Console.Write(art);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yeah, so the entire thing is about saving the array in a .txt file, then creating another method which allows to read the array out of the txt and then it needs to be split in 7 lines and 11 letters each line (and ofc, be converted into a space, the letters C and # to display this little "artwork").